# Minimum possible Clique in a Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, clique, clique-problem

Find the minimum possible size of a clique in a graph, that can be formed using n nodes and e edges. The component should be a complete graph.

In other words,
Find min size of subset of vertices such that every two distinct vertices that has a unique edge between all it's nodes.

- The given graph is considered to be undirected.
- Size refers to number of nodes in the clique.

example:

- given 5 nodes and 6 edges, min size of complete graph is 2 ([visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LZ4u.png))
- given 5 nodes and 7 edges, min size of complete graph is 3 ([visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyXq6.png))

Comment: Cool question! Would you mind sharing your attempts at this problem?

Comment: The word "component" is very confusing here because your problem is completely unrelated to "connected components". I think what you mean is "nodes-induced subgraph".

Comment: @Stef If I understand the question right, it's about min [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) size

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279241/minimum-size-of-largest-clique-in-a-graph) might be helpful

Comment: @Marat, you are right the question is about clique, I will go ahead and update the question to incorporate that

Comment: @Marat the link of the question you shared was what I was looking for, I will go ahead and post that answer here too, so that it helps in future.